# PHP Convert Multi-dimensional Array to Query String for curl POST

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I'm aware that curl's `POSTFIELDS` option will take either a query string or an associative array.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

But lets say I have a page with an input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="address[line1]">
```

PHP will create a multi-dimensional array `$_POST['address']['line1']`, which unfortunately `curl_setopt` doesn't know what to do with.  Is there some simple way to convert an associative array that is potentially multidimensional into a valid HTTP query string?

Alternately, is there some way to access the raw HTTP post query string like you can do with the get `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactlyi what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to create a string that you can pass to cURL:

```
<?php
$posted = ["foo"=>"bar", "address"=>["line1"=>"foo"]];
$string = http_build_query($posted);

echo $string;
```

Output:

```
foo=bar&address%5Bline1%5D=foo
```

You can also [get access to the raw POST data](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) using `input://` but that is rarely necessary, unless dealing with non-HTML data.